# Vertically center content inside a Semantic UI menu

Tags: css, alignment, semantic-ui

**See [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/designosis/hhae4cq0/).**

In Semantic UI, how does one create a horizontal menu with (a) vertically centered items, and (b) a vertical break between icon and text inside an item?

This code ...

```
<div class="ui icon menu">
    <div class="item">
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#f00"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        I want this<br>vertically centered
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <i class="huge blue settings icon"></i>
        I want these<br>beneath the icon
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <i class="huge blue power icon"></i>
        ... and centered<br>vertically
    </div>
</div>
```

... is close. Below is what happens before and after adding `labeled` to the menu.

[image]

Without `labeled` I can't figure out how to move the text below the image.

With `labeled`, I can't figure out how to vertically center the item contents.

Any advice?

**EDIT:** The easiest solution would be to answer the question "How do you force a line-break between an icon and text in the item?"

Comment: use frameworks, and then heroically overcome the resulting problems... you have interrupts semantic styles. you should either use `!important` or to abandon the typical class names like `item`

Comment: lol absolutely true ... though with Semantic UI often the developers add undocumented workarounds (like adding a `content` div inside the `item`) that changes the behavior ... i guess i'm hoping I'm not the first to want text below icons in a menu :)

Comment: can you recommend a universal solution - don't use frameworks )))

Comment: client required it :\ i prefer homebrew as well.

Comment: u can change html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that without changing HTML and CSS code.

```css
.item {
  background-color: #aa8 !important;
}

.item div {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui labeled icon menu">
  <div class="item">
    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#f00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      I want this
      <br>vertically centered
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <i class="huge blue settings icon"></i> I want these
      <br>beneath the icon
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div> <i class="huge grey power icon"></i> ... and centered
      <br>vertically
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet looks the same as my first example ("without labeled class").

Like the example, it's vertically centered, but the icons are still to the left of the text. How do I push the text below the icons?

Comment: do not understand. is there a way?

Comment: @neokio i change my answer